# How to make an html div appear like a separate form or window using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Let me first explain what I want to happen.

I have 2 browse buttons for Team and Country. Whenever the user clicks any of the browse button a list of Team or Country will appear in a different form. When the form is appearing or active the page should only focus on the form. Only when the user selects from the list or cancel selecting will he be able to focus on the main form. I want it similar like in Facebook when you suggest friends to a friend.

I would suggest that you run my code so you can see what I'm trying to do.

**`index.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function hideBrowseOption (optionId) {
  document.getElementById(optionId).style.display = 'none';
 }

 function showBrowseOption (optionId) {
  document.getElementById(optionId).style.display = '';
 }

 function selectTeam (teamId) {
  document.getElementById('fpTeamTxt').value = document.getElementById(teamId).innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('optionTeam').style.display = 'none';
 }

 function selectCountry (countryId) {
  document.getElementById('fpCountryTxt').value = document.getElementById(countryId).innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('optionCountry').style.display = 'none';
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="hideBrowseOption ('optionTeam'); hideBrowseOption ('optionCountry');">

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" id="fpNameTxt" name="fpNameTxt">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Team:</td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" id="fpTeamTxt" name="fpTeamTxt">
   <input type="button" id="fpTeamBrowse" name="fpTeamBrowse" value="Browse" onclick="showBrowseOption ('optionTeam')">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Country:</td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" id="fpCountryTxt" name="fpCountryTxt">
   <input type="button" id="fpCountryBrowse" name="fpCountryBrowse" value="Browse" onclick="showBrowseOption ('optionCountry')">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div id="optionTeam">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td id="team1">FC Bayern</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectTeam ('team1');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="team2">Real Madrid</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectTeam ('team2');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="team3">FC Barcelona</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectTeam ('team3');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="team4">Manchester United</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectTeam ('team4');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="team5">Santos</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectTeam ('team5');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="team6">AC Milan</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectTeam ('team6');"> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="hideBrowseOption ('optionTeam');" > 
</div>

<div id="optionCountry">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td id="country1">Germany</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectCountry ('country1');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="country2">Portugal</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectCountry ('country2');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="country3">Spain</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectCountry ('country3');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="country4">England</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectCountry ('country4');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="country5">Brazil</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectCountry ('country5');"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="country6">Italy</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectCountry ('country6');"> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="hideBrowseOption ('optionCountry');" > 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I want to do it using native JavaScript.

I really need your help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to get a model window with the information you want to display. You can use a jQuery based JavaScript solution like prettyPhoto to get that effect.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

take a look at loading external sites/iframe on the documentation.

Comment: Can I do it without using jQuery but native Javascript instead?

Comment: try this,this is a native JavaScript lightbox (pretty photo is actually a clone of this) http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: @ChickenBoy: Yes you can, everything is feasible in javascript that is possible in jquery

Answer (score 2):

**Your**

```
function showBrowseOption (optionId) { 
  document.getElementById(optionId).style.display = ''; 
 }
```

Should Be Like this

```
        function showBrowseOption (optionId) { 
              document.getElementById(optionId).style.display = ''; 
    document.getElementById(optionId).style.position = 'fixed';
     document.getElementById(optionId).style.width = '800px';
    document.getElementById(optionId).style.height = '500px';
    document.getElementById(optionId).left = '150px';
document.getElementById(optionId).style.overflow = 'scroll';
             }
```

Comment: Thanks but I can still type on the main page. I want the page to be disabled when the form is active.